# Creating subdomain / virtualhost in apache on CentOS 6.2

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost

I've been trying to make a subdomain to host my forum to make it look better than www.mydomain.co.uk/forum/index.php  i want it to be forum.mydomain.co.uk

I've tried all the tutorials, guides and everything i've found on google, but nothing works. I've tried using webmin but that just made things more complicated and i had to reinstall everything from scratch because it wrecked it up. Here's what i have below, could anyone tell me if there's anything other than this that i must do for the subdomain to work?

The contents of my httpd.conf are:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin email@email.com
     ServerName forum.mydomain.co.uk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/forum
     ErrorLog logs/forum-error_log
     CustomLog logs/forum-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The domain itself works. It points to my apache page which is what I need for now because I haven't uploaded anything. When I go to mydomain.co.uk/forum it, shows the index of forum contents. forum.mydomain.co.uk shows page cannot be displayed / unable to resolve host.

Are there any other files i must configure for this to work?

Comment: did you point your sub domains a-record?

Comment: You mean with the domain regestrar? I created an A record there for it to point to the IP address. When i did that the subdomain worked, but when i went to my home page it would show the content of my subdomain instead of my homepage

Comment: in your cPanel or admin panel, where is your subDomains folder pointed to?  it should a folder outside of your regular domain, un accessible from your domain

Comment: I'm not using cpanel or any admin panel. Just trying to do it by configuring apache and the right files. I've only configured httpd.conf at the moment. According to the guides i've read on how to do it, it should be working already but it isnt.

Answer (score 19):

- go to your registrar and point the **sub-domains A-Record** to your static ip
- inside httpd.conf make sure this line exists: **NameVirtualHost *:80**

the name of my folder where all the html and php files reside: **mydirectory**
full path from root: /var/www/mydirectory
this is my httpd.conf on ec2 linux

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.beta.myDomain.com
    ServerAlias beta.myDomain.com
    ServerAdmin tech@myDomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydirectory"
    <Directory /var/www/beta.myDomain.com/>
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- then after all that is done reload your webserver: **sudo service httpd reload**
- remember that it can take up to 24 hours for the registrar to propagate

Comment: I tried with this

    `<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.forum.mydomain.co.uk
        ServerAlias forum.mydomain.co.uk
        ServerAdmin tech@myDomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/forum.mydomain.co.uk
        <Directory /var/www/forum.mydomain.co.uk>
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>`

Still nothing.

Comment: Do i need to do anything with my domain regestrar? For example, i have my domain pointing to the server ip address. Do i need to make forum.mydomain.co.uk point to the ip address too? Just when i did this before it was causing my home page to display the subdomain content.

Comment: Set the A-record in my server or with my domain registrar?

Comment: I'm with domainexpress.co.uk for my domain supplier. I have a dedi hosted with another company. I went onto domainexpress and set an A record for forum.mydomain.co.uk to the ip address of my server.

After a few hours it propagated and now the subdomain is showing the apache page, the same as the home page is. If i upload a page to my subdomain forum.mydomain.co.uk i can access it by doing mydomain.co.uk/file.php.

Comment: The httpd.conf is configured according to what i've been told on here. Are there any other files to configre or any other settings? When i was using cpanel with another host, i didn't need to setup an A record with my domain registrar, for subdomains to work.

Comment: your folder should be DocumentRoot /var/www/html/forum  that means you should NOT be able to access it from mydomain.co.uk/file.php.  you need to have a folder here: /var/www/html/forum.  then file.php should be inside the directory 'forum'

Comment: The instructions to do this are everywhere on the internet. I just can't understand why it isn't working when i follow it exactly as it says. I'm new to this so it's useless assuming i've done this and that in other files or folders.

My previous host supplied cPanel, in that i used the subdomains option and didn't need to create an A record with my domain regestrar for this to work. I've created one now and yeah it works but its showing the homepage, not the page i want it to show. If i have /var/www/html/forum and a file in there called info.php it will show if i use >>>>

Comment: >>>  forum.mydomain.co.uk/info.php  but if i have another file called index in /var/www/html and i goto forum.mydomain.co.uk/index.php i see that page. If i do mydomain.co.uk/info.php i also see the page. It isn't duplicated in both folders, but i can access it from both addresses. I've got an A record on my regestrar pointing to the IP address of my server, so that would explain that. Then if i delete that A record, how can i create one in apache on my servr instead? I'm searching and not finding anything that works.

Comment: you might need to create a virtual host for mydomain.co.uk as well.  refresh apache after you do

Comment: I created virtual host in the httpd.conf file as shown above, then i service httpd restart. Nothing ever works. I installed webmin and tried creating it through that, didn't work either.

Comment: if i could add you a 100000 upvote, trust me, I would